# TXMLDocument 'Invalid pointer operation' when freeing

Tags: xml, delphi, exception, delphi-xe2

I'm using the `TXMLDocument` to write an XML string which is used in a web server. The component is created when the server receives the request, produces XML, passes it back to the client, then the component is free'd. However, when this component is free'd, I get `Invalid pointer operation`.

```
  XML:= TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
  try
    XML.Active:= True;
    nRoot:= XML.AddChild('topics');
    for X := 0 to FCHM.Topics.Count - 1 do begin
      nTopic:= nRoot.AddChild('topic');
      //Add more data...

    end;
    Response.ContentText:= XML.XML.Text;
    Response.ContentType:= 'text/xml';
    XML.Active:= False;
  finally
    XML.Free; //<-- Invalid pointer operation
  end;
```

Why am I getting this and how do I get rid of it?

Strangely, although I can confirm that `Response.ContentText` did in fact get the XML, for some reason the web server fails to return this data back to the client after this exception - but I'm assuming that's a different cause/effect issue.

PS - `CoInitialize(nil)` and `CoUninitialize` are called around this handler since the web server is multi-threaded and the `TXMLDocument` is COM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's stated in the [`constructor's`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Xml.XMLDoc.TXMLDocument.Create) reference:

> TXMLDocument components that are created at runtime without an owner
>   are freed automatically when all references to their IXMLDocument
>   interface are released.

Since you've specified no `Owner` in your `TXMLDocument` constructor call, you should not release it by yourself.

Comment: Wow, I would have never expected that to be the case. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Or, you should use the function Delphi has for that purpose: `iDoc := NewXMLDocument;` where `iDoc` is variable of `IXMLDocument` type.

Comment: You're welcome. Anyway, as an alternative you can declare your `XML` variable as `IXMLDocument` and to create a new document call [`NewXMLDocument`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Xml.XMLDoc.NewXMLDocument) function.

Comment: It's not enough just to remove the free. You have to take a reference to an interface implemented by the object. And that means changing the type of the variable that you assign the result of the constructor. Typically to IXMLDocument.

Comment: I know this is 10 years old, but a google search brought me here and incase it does the same to someone else - it appears there is a bug in the XML classes in Delphi, if you pass nil in a constructor. Just calling any method of TXMLDocument after loading the xml file (i.e. xmlDoc.DocumentElement;) will result in an InvalidPointer error raised from the depths of the XML class. I fixed it by passing Application.MainForm into the constructor.